# "Edit" action, save old data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How i can save old data in action [post]Edit?

I have these two models:

```
public class Task
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int sheet_length { get; set; }
    public int sheets_num { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int spoolID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("spoolID")]
    public virtual Spool Spool { get; set; }
}

public class Spool
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int weight { get; set; }
    public int weight_meter { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

When I create Task - Spool.Weight changes
    Task.Spool.Weight = Task.Spool.Weight - (Task.sheet_length * Task.sheets_num * Task.Spool.weight_meter)

When I edit a task - I want to do this:

```
TaskOld.Spool.Weight = TaskOld.Spool.Weight + (TaskOld.sheet_length * TaskOld.sheets_num * TaskOld.Spool.weight_meter)

Task.Spool.Weight = Task.Spool.Weight - (Task.sheet_length * Task.sheets_num * Task.Spool.weight_meter)
```

But when I try to get old data in edit action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Task task)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        taskOld = dbContext.Tasks.Single (t => t.ID == task.ID);

        ////some code

        db.Tasks.Attach(task);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Task", new { id = task.orderID });
    }
 ///some code }
```

I get an ObjectStateManager error (it has object with the same key)

Comment: I'm not sure this work, but couldn't you just update `taskOld` with the changed values in `task` and then `SaveChanges`?

Comment: Reading back, one thing that you don't make clear at all - are you trying to retain the old task and insert a new task during edit?  Your question makes it sound like that now that I reread it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs when you attach the new task.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    taskOld = dbContext.Tasks.Single (t => t.ID == task.ID);

    ////some code

    // Error here! db.Tasks already contains something for the Id
    // Can't have two tasks with the same Id.  Attach doesn't update the
    // existing record, but adds the 'task' to the object graph for tracking.
    db.Tasks.Attach(task);

    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Task", new { id = task.orderID });
}
```

Both have the same Id, and the ObjectStateManager can't track two of the same object with the same Id.

A more normal approach is to map the Task input to taskOld:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    taskOld = dbContext.Tasks.Single (t => t.ID == task.ID);

    // ... Some code ...

    // taskOld is already attached to the DbContext, so just map the updated
    // properties.
    taskOld.Property1 = task.Property1;
    taskOld.Property2 = task.Property2;
    ...

    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Task", new { id = task.orderID });
}
```

Or, instead of assigning properties individually, you can call `UpdateModel(taskOld)` and it will attempt to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can following Leniency code, or:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Task t)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View(t);
}
```